# cannot find symbol "return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();" react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-code-push library..
And installed using `yarn add react-native-code-push`

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 I:\foodon
> app
> reactnative\reactnative\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnative\MainApplication.java:31:
> error: cannot find symbol
> return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
> ^   symbol: variable CodePush Note: I:\foodon app reactnative\reactnative\android\app\src\debug\java\com\reactnative\ReactNativeFlipper.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to configure codepush, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-get-started#plugin-installation-and-configuration-for-react-native-060-version-and-above-android)

Comment: yes I followed that...I forgot to add packages